# how to adhere a stainless steel backsplash to painted drywall surface

Tags: backsplash

I have a 30" x 21" 22 ga. stainless steel backsplash with 4 (3/16") mounting holes 3/4" from edges.  Since I will be using 4 screws to put it up, can I use removable (not permanent) double sided tape, e.g. DUCT brand, over much if not all of its surface to keep it from buckling or bowing out?  The sheet is set back from a cooktop by about 5 inches.

Comment: I cannot think of a single permanent application where duct tape should be used. A construction adhesive is advisable most of the time where an adhesive is needed. What are you going to be mounting this to? Drywall? Wood? More details are needed.

Comment: The OP isn't talking classic "duct tape", but double-sided tape. Different animal.

Comment: Aside from mention of removable tape, you haven't said whether it actually needs to be removable. Most removable products tend to work loose over time and with heat cycling, especially around cooking appliances.

Comment: What does the maker of the backsplash say?  Do they indicate it will bow out or warp with time?  If not them, what is your concern based on?  
To me, if it is flat now it will not buckle or bow out when attached with 4 drywall-appropriate fasteners.

Comment: 22 ga. isn't exactly heavy. I'd expect some oil-canning or vibration without something behind it.

Comment: The manufacturer recommends glue or permanent double sided mounting tape, both of which will damage the painted drywall underneath.  I would like to have the flexibility of being able to remove the piece.  I asked to see if anyone had actually done what I described and if it worked out for them.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that it'll get warm at times and use a product that won't goo apart as a result. Anything that's stiff will leave you with ripples visible from the side.

A panel adhesive that lists suitability for metal will give you a smooth finish and lasting bond. Use a small v-notch trowel to distribute it flatly and evenly to avoid rippling.

Alternatively, attach a sheet of felt to the back with double-sided tape to act as a vibration and noise dampener and just use the four screws.